# Why was this closed?

Tags: support

[How is three phase power delivered and used in Malta?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/266440/41478)

I got lovely answers which answered the problems and misunderstandings. So why the close?

Answer (score 2):

If I had to guess it's because it isn't really a home improvement question. It's more about travel/emigration information and electrical theory. If you had asked something more specific, such as how to use a particular appliance, it might've been considered more topical to this site.